# Retcode=10016 when executing a trade in metatrader 5

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader5

I'm getting retcode=10016 ('Invalid stops') when trying to use a stop loss larger than 0.0. If left at 0.0 the trade will execute fine and close whenever the moving averages crossover again.

Here is the variables for stop loss and take profit market order function:

```
sl = 25.00
tp = 100.00

def market_order(symbol, volume, order_type, sl, tp, deviation=20, magic=12345):

    order_type_dict = {
        'buy': mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY,
        'sell': mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
    }
    
    price_dict = {
        'buy': mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask,
        'sell': mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
    }
    
    request = {
        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "volume": volume,  # FLOAT
        "type": order_type_dict[order_type],
        "price": price_dict[order_type],
        "sl": sl,  # FLOAT
        "tp": tp,  # FLOAT
        "deviation": deviation,  # INTERGER
        "magic": magic,  # INTERGER
        "comment": strategy_name,
        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC,
        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC,
    }
    
    order_result = mt5.order_send(request)
    return(order_result)
```

I've tried adding sl and tp into this same error occurs

```
if num_positions == 0 and check_allowed_trading_hours():
    order_result = market_order(symbol, volume, 'buy', sl, tp)
    print(order_result)
```

```
if num_positions == 0 and check_allowed_trading_hours():
    order_result = market_order(symbol, volume, 'sell', sl, tp)
    print(order_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check specification of your Symbol. It is part of Market Watch (please see https://www.metatrader5.com/en/terminal/help/trading/market_watch#specification for details). Your broker defined some parameters that can be source of this error. First of all check "Stops level" parameter. It is defined as:

*Stops level — channel of prices (in points) from the current price, inside which one can't place Stop Loss, Take Profit and pending orders. When placing an order inside the channel, the server will return message "Invalid Stops" and will not accept the order.*

For example, my broker set this parameter to 0 for AUDUSD and 10 for BRN. As result, I can set any stop level for AUDUSD, but for BRN minimal difference in stop levels **must** be 10 points from buying/selling price.

Additonaly check number of decimal points in "sl" and "tp" variables. If you send variable with to many decimal points, server will (most probably) reject your request.

Hope this will put people with this problem in right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify:

```
"sl": price_dict[order_type] -sl*_Point,  
"tp": price_dict[order_type] +tp*_Point,
```

Before this you should insert:

```
if (order_type_dict[order_type] == ORDER_TYPE_SELL) {      
 sl    = -sl;
 tp    = -tp;
}
```